# jqm flipswitch, float label left, switch right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying to get a bunch of flipswitches on a page in a mobile app.

I am using:

```
<div class="ui-content">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="checkbox-based-flipswitch">Checkbox-based:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-based-flipswitch" data-role="flipswitch">
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

It seems my "container" field is shortened. It does not stretch the entire width of the screen.

[image: Ripple Emulator Screenshot. Same rendering on device]

What am I missing?

I am looking to have the option fill the entire width of the screen. Label left, flipswitch right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case a jQM grid might work better for you than a fieldcontain:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a flipContain">
  <div class="ui-block-a">
      <label for="chk1">Checkbox-based:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-b">
      <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" data-role="flipswitch" />
  </div>

  <div class="ui-block-a">
      <label for="chk2">Checkbox-based:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-b">
      <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" data-role="flipswitch" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Then with CSS, you can align the second column to the right and set the column widths as desired:

```
.flipContain .ui-block-a {
    width: 70%;
    line-height: 48px;
}
.flipContain .ui-block-b {
    width: 30%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently [field-contain](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/forms-field-contain/) has been deprecated in 1.4 and will be removed in 1.5.

Can't you use a table width 100% and table cell ?
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdvh93e4/1/)

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td><label for="checkbox-based-flipswitch">Checkbox-based:</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-based-flipswitch" data-role="flipswitch"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And you can set the cell alignement as you want, as in the exemple both are centered.

```
td{
   text-align:center;
}
```

You can set the alignment directly on the td [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdvh93e4/2/) :

```
<td align="right">
```

Comment: I was contemplating that, but I would have liked JQM to actually just work as it is supposed to...